# How to assign Appskey & AltGr ( LCtrl & RAlt ) as a Hotkey in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I've tried this, But it didn't work :

```
AppsKey & LCtrl & RAlt::MsgBox, abcd
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like that:

```
#if GetKeyState("AppsKey", "P")
LCtrl & RAlt::MsgBox Hotkey activated.
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

If your keyboard layout has [AltGr](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm#AltGr) instead of a right Alt key, you can try

```
; Appskey + AltGr 
AppsKey & RAlt::MsgBox, abcd
```

and it will work even if you change the keyboard layout.

To avoid that the [prefix key](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm#combo) loses its native function, add

```
AppsKey::Send, {AppsKey}
```